# Calculated Items in Excel: How to check if a field contains a particular item

Tags: vba, excel

As part of my VBA script I'm trying to add a calculated item to a pivot field as follows:

```
myPivotTable.PivotFields("Validity").CalculatedItems.Add "Valid %", "=ROUND(('Rejected'+'Duplicate')/('Valid'+'Rejected'+'Duplicate') * 100, 1)"
```

In my source data table amongst other columns I have a 'Validity' column (the name of the field) with rows of data that can contain the values 'Valid' or 'Rejected' or 'Duplicate'. The above line will work fine when the source data column contains at least one row for each of those values.

Sometimes though my data set doesn't contain a row with 'Duplicate' so I get an error 400 when this is run.

I tried to use the IFNA, IFERROR functions to try and return 0 like this but this produces the same error:

```
myPivotTable.PivotFields("Validity").CalculatedItems.Add "Valid %", "=ROUND(('Rejected'+ IFNA(0, 'Duplicate'))/('Valid'+'Rejected'+ IFNA(0, 'Duplicate')) * 100, 1)"
```

How can I fix this?